# Using capture buffers in a Perl regular expression stored in a variable

Tags: regex, perl

I am receiving the left and right sides of a regular expression replacement as the arguments to a function.  I want my users to be able to use capture buffers, but it doesn't work the way I'm trying to do it.

```
my $string = "This is my string";

$string = regex_replace($string,'is (my) string','$1');

print "$string\n";

sub regex_replace {
    my ( $string,$left,$right ) = @_;

    $string =~ s/$left/$right/gsm;

    return $string;
}
```

Executing this outputs "This $1" instead of the "This my" I am trying to get.  Is there any way to accomplish what I am trying to do here?

Comment: Do you really need to do this operation in a sub?  Perl != PHP. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to avoid the use of eval...

```
my $string = "This is my string";

$string = regex_replace($string,'is (my) string','$1');

print "$string\n";

sub regex_replace {
    my ( $string,$left,$right ) = @_;

    $string =~ /$left/g;
    $rv = $1;
    $right =~ s/\$1/$rv/;

    $string =~ s/$left/$right/gsm;

    return $string;
}
```

Comment: I think I'll want to tweak this a bit to allow the use of more than one capture buffer, but I think this is the way to go.

Answer (score 0):

In `regex_replace`, you could use

```
eval "\$string =~ s/$left/$right/gsm";
```

but `eval STRING` gives people the heebie-jeebies.

With your example, the output is

```
This my
```